# Spring @Scheduled is it possible to set it up not with bean creation

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I have a trouble with setting up this param with a value which I should recieve from server.

If I use this annotation `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)` I should set a constant as a value.

I know that there is another option `@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${my.value}")`, however I need to set a value which I recieve from server.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is the value known at Spring startup time?  Or do you only have access to the value AFTER spring has already started up?

Comment: just after Spring has started up

Comment: We also have a configuration module which fetches configs from server and set it to bean which created on Spring startup. but I'm not able to inject this value into the annotation

Comment: Question Resolved. I haven't found how to fix this issue with Spring functionality. I just created my own scheduler with ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor